# Edit "Discussions List" fields programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to update the "IsQuestion" field withe OOTB "Discussions List", but the following error appears:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for error is that you need to use the Display name of the field which is `Question` and not `IsQuestion`(internal name). Change code to `SPField field = list.Fields["Question"];`

Comment: thank you I use list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("IsQuestion")